# gitlab-ee on GCE periodically stops accepting traffic, but works again after restart

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gitlab

TLDR; I have gitlab running on a GCE vm. Occasionally the vm stops accepting traffic as though there is some external firewall in play. resetting the vm fixes things. I can use google's tooling to ssh in. From the inside everything looks fine.

My question: How do I stop this?

## longer version

I have a GCE instance on which I am running gitlab (9.5.1-ee).

```
lsb_release -a
=> 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:        17.04
Codename:       zesty
```

I ssh into the instance and:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log
```

accessing my instance via my broser works fine and gets logged in the usual way. Ssh'ing into the vm and doing a curl also works as expected.

Now for the strange part. I've been hitting my head on this for a while now.

Occasionally the gitlab instance just stops working. I cant git pull/push. I cant access the web app in my browser. when I tail the access log like before I get no new info when trying to access the instance from the outside (via my browser or whatever), but doing curls from inside the vm works the same.

It's like there is a firewall in the way. There really shouldn't be.

I then reset the vm and everything works fine for a while. And then it breaks again.

It seems like a Google infrastructure issue, but I cant find anything in the logs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## UPDATE

I can ping my gitlab domain from inside the VM always, and I can't ping it when it is acting down. It's definately not a DNS thing.

I figured I could see where the traffic stops by doing a traceroute and it acts pretty much the same whether it is up or down.  Eg:

```
  1   192.168.12.1  10.350ms  2.163ms  4.095ms 
  2   196.41.120.41  51.029ms  14.084ms  5.177ms 
  3   196.41.120.37  34.846ms  38.931ms  3.306ms 
  4   196.41.97.74  11.717ms  7.113ms  5.196ms 
  5   74.125.146.178  7.322ms  18.239ms  8.329ms 
  6   66.249.95.8  209.010ms  203.518ms  176.016ms 
  7   64.233.175.113  174.606ms  167.839ms  166.019ms 
  8   209.85.252.120  174.138ms  169.820ms  173.657ms 
  9   108.170.234.139  196.385ms  169.107ms  168.493ms 
 10   *  *  *
```

There is no useful pattern there that I can see.

Also, this started randomly last week. Nobody had touched the VM. I ran some updates after the funky stuff started happening and it didn't fix anything.

As far as I can tell something is wrong with the infrastructure supporting my vm. It's like there is a firewall that occasionally pops up just for fun, and then goes away when I reset.

Seriously stumped here. some help would be nice

## update 2

`ufw status` tells me the firewall is disabled. Always. So it's not like the VM's internal firewall is magically turning itself on and off either. As far as I can tell traffic just isn't reaching the vm at all.

## update 3

Using nmap from my local machine when gitlab is not responding:

```
nmap -Pn x.x.x.x                                                                  
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-30 12:40 SAST
...
Stats: 0:02:48 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing SYN Stealth Scan
SYN Stealth Scan Timing: About 83.50% done; ETC: 12:44 (0:00:33 remaining)
Nmap scan report for x.x.x.x.bc.googleusercontent.com (35.187.189.117)
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on x.x.x.x.bc.googleusercontent.com (x.x.x.x) are filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 201.62 seconds
```

And when gitlab is responding:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-30 12:47 SAST
Nmap scan report for x.x.x.x.bc.googleusercontent.com (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.26s latency).
Not shown: 994 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  open   https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
4567/tcp open   tram
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
```

And from the VM, the nmap output is the same regardless of whether gitlab is responding or not:

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-08-30 10:48 UTC
Nmap scan report for x.x.x.x.bc.googleusercontent.com (x.x.x.x)
Host is up (0.00069s latency).
Not shown: 994 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  open   https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
4567/tcp open   tram
8080/tcp closed http-proxy
Device type: general purpose|specialized|WAP|PBX|phone|media device
Running (JUST GUESSING): Linux 3.X|4.X (89%), Crestron 2-Series (88%), Asus embedded (88%), Vodavi embedded (88%), Google Android 5.X (86%)
OS CPE: cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3.2 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:4.2 cpe:/o:crestron:2_series cpe:/h:asus:rt-n56u cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3.4 cpe:/h:vodavi:xts-ip cpe:/o:google:android:5 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:3.x
Aggressive OS guesses: Linux 3.2 (89%), Linux 4.2 (89%), Crestron XPanel control system (88%), ASUS RT-N56U WAP (Linux 3.4) (88%), Linux 3.16 (88%), Vodavi XTS-IP PBX (88%), Android 5.0 - 5.1 (86%), Android 5.1 (86%), Linux 3.13 (86%), Linux 3.2 - 3.10 (86%)
No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).

OS detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 24.30 seconds
```

Comment: please accompany downvotes with comments. because common decency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was SshGuard. Not sure why it decided my local netwrk ip was evil, but anyway. It's just a matter of reconfiguring that.